# Line 28: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to make this work for hours now. Whenever I run the code it keeps giving me a "Line 28:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression" error.

```
import React from "react";

class Brewery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breweries: []
    };
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          breweries: data,
        })
      })
  }

  render() {

    const { breweries } = this.state;

    return(
        <ul>
          {breweries.map((brewery) => {
              <li key={brewery.id}>
                {brewery.name}
              </li>
          })}
        </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default Brewery;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably you are not returning anything in your `.map` method.

```
  <ul>
    {breweries.map(brewery => {
      <li key={brewery.id}>{brewery.name}</li>;
    })}
  </ul>
```

Here, you are using fat arrow function with a body block but not using `return`, so add it:

```
  <ul>
    {breweries.map(brewery => {
      return <li key={brewery.id}>{brewery.name}</li>;
    })}
  </ul>
```

or use [implicit return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body):

```
  <ul>
    {breweries.map(brewery => (
      <li key={brewery.id}>{brewery.name}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
```